# Fatal error: Uncaught SoapFault exception: [WSDL] SOAP-ERROR: Parsing WSDL: Couldn't load from

Tags: php, soap, wamp

I'm doing some SOAP exercises

But, I cannot get that to work on WAMP.

Error which I'm getting is:

> Fatal error: Uncaught SoapFault exception: [WSDL] SOAP-ERROR: Parsing WSDL: Couldn't 
>           load from 'https://www.creditsafe.fr/getdata/service/CSFRServices.asmx?WSDL:8080' : failed to load external entity
>            "https://www.creditsafe.fr/getdata/service/CSFRServices.asmx?WSDL:8080" in C:\wamp\www\GESTION\add_debiteur.php:128 Stack trace: #0 
>       C:\wamp\www\GESTION\add_debiteur.php(128): SoapClient->SoapClient('https://www.cre...') #1 
>       C:\wamp\www\GESTION\index.php(1360): include('C:\wamp\www\GES...') #2 {main} thrown in 
>       C:\wamp\www\GESTION\add_debiteur.php on line 128

```
$client = new SoapClient("http://footballpool.dataaccess.eu/data/info.wso?WSDL");
$wsdl = "https://www.creditsafe.fr/getdata/service/CSFRServices.asmx?WSDL";
$client = new SoapClient($wsdl);
```

Google does not know the answer. Any suggestion much appreciated.

Comment: possible duplicate of [SOAP-ERROR: Parsing WSDL: Couldn't load from](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11082889/soap-error-parsing-wsdl-couldnt-load-from)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The trouble was solved. In fact when I had so errors using WAMP(orange icon) I decided to set it up again.

So I installed the newest version of WAMP but there was no the same php.ini as I used  previously and in fact the trouble was that on the php.ini I had to make active the line `;extension=php_openssl.dll`

so I just removed the `;`character  and this line has become like `extension=php_openssl.dll`

Now it works fine.

Answer (score 14):

you can try this

```
echo file_get_contents($wsdl);
die();
```

and them you can view if you can access to $wsdl from php.

Answer (score 0):

I have installed wamp server 3.0 and I got the same error (Fatal error: Uncaught SoapFault exception: [WSDL] SOAP-ERROR: Parsing WSDL: Couldn't load).

To solve it, I have uncommented in my php.ini file below line of code:

**;extension=php_openssl.dll**

After enabling this line, restart your Wamp server. It's working for me.

Answer (score 0):

ini_set("default_socket_timeout", "300");

or php.ini change (default_socket_timeout). Work