# PHP and OpenSSL stopped working after service change

Tags: php, hosting, php-openssl

Recently I asked my hosting company to setup a new package and since then my existing package is now giving me errors with anything to do with using openSSL.

For instance, I have a function to generate a GUID:

```
function generateGUIDV4($data)
{
    assert(strlen($data) == 16);
    $data[6] = chr(ord($data[6]) & 0x0f | 0x40); // set version to 0100
    $data[8] = chr(ord($data[8]) & 0x3f | 0x80); // set bits 6-7 to 10
    return vsprintf('%s%s-%s-%s-%s-%s%s%s', str_split(bin2hex($data), 4));
}

$newID = generateGUIDV4(openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(16));
```

This now throws an error: `Fatal error: Call to undefined function openssl_random_pseudo_bytes()`. From what I've researched this has to do with [Fatal error: Call to undefined function openssl_random_pseudo_bytes()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11212808/fatal-error-call-to-undefined-function-openssl-random-pseudo-bytes).

Now I'm also getting an error now when I call any web services from my application which again point to the openSSL.

**Error**:

```
Objectfaultcode: "WSDL"faultstring: "SOAP-ERROR: Parsing WSDL: Couldn't load from 'https://*******'"__proto__: Object
```

.I've hidden the web service as it's not public. From what I've researched this points to OpenSSL again: [SOAP-ERROR: Parsing WSDL: Couldn't load from <URL>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11082889/soap-error-parsing-wsdl-couldnt-load-from-url).

**PHP Ini is showing openSSL IS installed**

```
OpenSSL support enabled
OpenSSL Version OpenSSL 0.9.8b 04 May 2006
```

Anyone have any ideas or point me in the right direction? I've got the hosting company looking into this.

Comment: What new package did they install?

Comment: They setup another hosting package - so basically a new area on a server so I can setup a new website, have FTP and point a domain at it etc...

Answer (score 0):

I've fixed this and it had nothing to do with the hosting company.

I published a new version of the site, but in the publish profile I told it to delete all files which deleted the .htaccess file which contained the version of PHP in.

Unfortunately, I needed version 5.4 or above to run my code but since the file was removed it dropped down to 5.2 of PHP.

So I've uploaded a new .htaccess file with the correct version in and everything is working.

Hopefully this may help someone if they're as daft as I am.